# How to customize Picking video style in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am working with video marge app. When i pick video from library using UIImagePicker, it is a default style like this photo. 
[image]

But I want like this. 
[image]
If i use ELCImagePicker i can pick video. but when i try to set the video in a video player it show null video url. Please help.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use mediative property of UIImagePickerController for selecting media of type video. here is sample code .

```
 UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie,      nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```